# How do I change Sublime Python comments color specifically?

Tags: python, colors, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I really liked the Monokai color theme, except for one thing - I can barely see the comments which are more than half the actual code text. Is there a way to change the color of the comments specifically but keep the rest according to monokai?

Comment: what do you mean by ***notes***?

Comment: in python the char '#' starts a note. In monokai they are gray and the background color is dark gray is they are almost invisible.

Comment: Ah I see, you mean comments!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those are the steps:

1. open the command palette in sublime text by typing:  Ctrl+Shift+P
2. type:  control install package
3. restart sublime text
4. Reenter again into the command palette by typing the same thing again
5. type prv and search for: PackageResourceViewer- Open resource
6. Click on: Color Scheme - Default and choose Monokai.tmTheme
7. When you enter the .xml file. go to line 54 I think (under the comment line)  and change that value to whaterver you want

For me i use: #26E372 // is a green color 
For yellow color you can use: #FFFF00

If you want to know wich number to choose: you can go to this site to know: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly. :) Changed from #75715E to #FFCD42

Comment: This is a huge help. Thank you for mapping out the steps!

Answer (score 20):

I was unable to change comments color by editing `Monokai.tmTheme`.

For Sublime 3.1.1 Build 3176 editing `Monokai.sublime-color-scheme` works.

---

**1. Open Package Resource Viewer**

[image: Open Package Resource viewer]

**2. Open Color Scheme**

[image: Open Color Scheme - Default]

**3. Open Monokai color scheme**

[image: Open Monokai color scheme]

**4. Add your desired color in `variables`** (pick [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp))

[image: Add you desired color]

**5. Change comment color**

[image: Change comment color]

**6. Enjoy your new comments color!**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, saved me quite a bit of time :)

Comment: What about multi-line comments? How do you change that color? ie: `""" my comment here """`. I'm not sure what that style of comment is called.

Comment: Nevermind. It's the same thing. The "name" "Comment" color field affects both `# regular comments` and `""" multiline comments"""` it seems.

Answer (score 14):

Changing specific components of a color scheme in `Sublime Text 3` is easily done via the **[PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)** plugin.

---

In simple steps:

- Install ***PackageResourceViewer*** as you would any plugin via Sublimes ***Package Manager***.
- Open the command pallette and search for ''***Open Resource***''.
- From the list select ***Color Scheme - Default*** and then select the monokai theme ***Monokai.tmTheme***.

From the **.xml** file scroll down until you see the ***comment*** entry holding the color value for the comments and change it to **#FFFFFF** as it can be seen in the picture:

[image: monokai.tmTheme]

Now comments will actually be more visible :-)

[image]

Of course you can change this value to whatever you wish.

Answer (score 7):

Adding on to Dschang123's great answer: to distinguish between single- and multi-line comments and their respective colors (which is what I personally came to this question searching for) one can change:

```
    {
        "name": "Comment",
        "scope": "comment",
        "foreground": "var(yellow5)"
    },
```

to instead read:

```
        {
            "name": "Comment_multi",
            "scope": "comment.block, punctuation.definition.comment.block",
            "foreground": "var(blue5)"
        },
        {
            "name": "Comment_single",
            "scope": "comment.line, punctuation.definition.comment.line",
            "foreground": "var(blue6)"
        },
```

(I like these colors for the Mariana theme but am not advertising my choice as optimal by any metrics).

Information on "scope" from: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html

(I'd comment this under Petr Javorik's answer in response to Gabriel Staples's comment, but my rep doesn't yet qualify to comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by @jbplasma, for Monokai theme in `Sublime Text Build 4126` I went to the menu option `Preferences -> Customise colour scheme` and filled out the right-hand pane of custom settings to contain this:

```
// Documentation at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html
{
    "variables":
    {
        "dimcomment": "hsl(60, 12%, 55%)",
        "brightcomment": "hsl(60, 12%, 75%)",
    },
    "globals":
    {
    },
    "rules":
    [
        {
            "name": "Comment_multi",
            "scope": "comment.block, punctuation.definition.comment.block",
            "foreground": "var(brightcomment)"
        },
        {
            "name": "Comment_single",
            "scope": "comment.line, punctuation.definition.comment.line",
            "foreground": "var(dimcomment)"
        },
    ]
}
```

This brightens up both block and line comments, making block comments a little lighter. You can change the brightness by adjusting the last percentage value, luminance, in the `hsl()` tuples.